# Private Video using YouTube API - Drupal

Tags: php, authentication, drupal, youtube-api

I want to set up my Drupal site to embed private videos from YouTube. I am the owner of these videos, and I have marked them as private to protect them from the general public.

From the documentation, I have seen how to do an authentication where the user is taken to youtube, has to log in to his account, and consent to give my web app access. Instead, I just want to always be logged in to a designated youtube account that has the necessary permissions. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I could use the ClientLogin auth method to get what I'm after, although the documentation sternly warns this is only to be used for desktop applications. I'm guessing it's only for security reasons, because they don't want services storing user's credentials. Obviously that's not the case here, as I just want to log in myself. I'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There was a discussion on this issue a few months back in [the Drupal forums](http://groups.drupal.org/node/19639).

The third comment is of interest as it specifically says that private videos can be embedded in your Drupal site and will be accessible once you login to Drupal. I have no first hand experience, so can't confirm or deny.

On a tangent, I've just finished working with developers in a situation where we had two sites, both pwd protected, and we wanted just one login gateway (i.e., once you login to either, you've logged into both). The solution of choice (and this may be way over the top for your needs) was simpleSAML.

Comment: Youtube appears to have changed it - even if embedding is permitted, it can't be shown if it is private and the user is not authenticated.

as for simpleSAML - I don't want people to be able to go to the designated youtube account and do stuff. I just want them to be able to see its content.

Comment: I have successfully authenticated with GData's ClientLogin API. Now it wants me to send the auth token in the http request to youtube. If I just have an embedded video on the page, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

try Dash Player for Drupal. What I did is host the videos in the site and this is how they look with Dash Player http://www.salvation123.com/node/35

You can actually add YouTube videos on a playlist just RTM on that ;-)